# How to change SnackBar's action font size?

Tags: flutter

I've a `SnackBar`:

```dart
SnackBar(
  content: Text('FooBar'),
  action: SnackBarAction(
    label: 'Action',
    onPressed: null,
  ),
);
```

How can I change the font size of `'Action'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the Snackbar's action font size by changing the **button** theme in the app's global theme. This is because the Snackbar's action is considered as a button. For example, set:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      button: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
    ),
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(title: appName),
);
```

The actions in Snackbars will be affected as desired.

Comment: But [it doesn't work using Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69019872/12483095) widget, any ideas?

Comment: A Theme widget for changing the snackbar's action font size is appliable to the whole screen's Scaffold only, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

the new
change button to labelLarge

```
 return MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      labelLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
    )
  )
);
```