# textTheme property not working using Theme widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm changing the `fontSize` of `SnackBarAction` using this code:

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(button: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)), // Doesn't work
        primaryColor: Colors.orange, // Works
      ),
      child: Builder(builder: (builderContext) {
        return FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: Text('SnackBar'),
              action: SnackBarAction(
                label: 'Dismiss',
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            );
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(builderContext).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.slideshow,
            color: Theme.of(builderContext).primaryColor,
          ),
        );
      }),
    ),
  );
}
```

The `fontSize` property seems to have no effect, however if I use the same `ThemeData` in `MaterialApp` widget (like the following) it works.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(button: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)), // Works
  ),
  home: SomePage(),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said by [esentis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12413404/esentis) your `Theme` widget should be parent of your `Scaffold`.

The reason for this is because your `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)` is refering to the descendant `Scaffold` as said in its documentation:

> Manages [SnackBar]s for descendant [Scaffold]s.

But as your `Theme` is not a parent of the `Scaffold` it will take the `Scaffold`'s theme into account and not the one you've wrapped your `FloatingActionButton` with.

The `Theme` you've added is further down in the widget tree so the `Scaffold` is not aware of its existence.

[documentation source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldMessenger-class.html)

### Edit

It's working when you are calling `Theme.of(builderContext).primaryColor` because in the current `builderContext` you have access to your `ThemeData` updated by the `Theme` widget.

In the case of `ScaffoldMessenger.of(builderContext)` the `builderContext` is used to find the `ScaffoldMessengerState` which will be used to have access to a descendant `Scaffold` in which you will display your snackbar. But when rendering your `SnackBar.content` which is a `Text` widget without a `style` property it will apply the default behavior of the widget which is implemented as follow in the `text.dart` source:

```dart
final DefaultTextStyle defaultTextStyle = DefaultTextStyle.of(context);
TextStyle? effectiveTextStyle = style;
if (style == null || style!.inherit)
  effectiveTextStyle = defaultTextStyle.style.merge(style);
```

And here's what is said in the [Flutter Text class API Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html):

> The `style` argument is optional. When omitted, the text will use the
> style from the closest enclosing `DefaultTextStyle`. If the given
> style's `TextStyle.inherit` property is true (the default), the given
> style will be merged with the closest enclosing `DefaultTextStyle`. This
> merging behavior is useful, for example, to make the text bold while
> using the default font family and size.

And in this case as the `style` property is `null` it will use the `DefaultTextStyle.of(context)`, **BUT** in this widget's `context` (which is not your `builderContext`) it doesn't have your new `ThemeData` so it will apply the base one.

Here's a way to have the `fontSize` you want without moving the `Theme` widget to prove my point:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        textTheme: const TextTheme(button: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),
      ),
      child: Builder(builder: (builderContext) {
        return FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            final snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: Text(
                'SnackBar',
                style: Theme.of(builderContext).textTheme.button, // Works
              ),
              action: SnackBarAction(
                label: 'Dismiss',
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            );
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(builderContext).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.slideshow),
        );
      }),
    ),
  );
}
```

[You can also test the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=9a606a69c5f5b2c68290dfdfd61d7221&null_safety=true)

In this code I am defining the `style` property of my `Text` widget using the `builderContext` which is a child of `Theme` so it is aware of the changes in the `ThemeData` in this context and as my `style` property is not null it won't rely on the `defaultTextStyle`.

Comment: That means using a `Builder` as the parent of `Theme` should work, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Why would it work ? The `context` provided by `Builder` would still find the same `Scaffold` in the widget tree which is not aware in its state of the modifications you've made by using `Theme`.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question, you can see `primaryColor` set in `Theme` widget works after using `builderContext`, however, the `fontSize` still doesn't work. This is why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your edit +1, however, I was talking about `SnackBarAction` which doesn't have any `style` property associated with it.

Comment: Yes you don't have a `style` for `SnackBarAction` but the answer to: "Why the textTheme is not applied to SnackBarAction ?" is the same, it is because the action doesn't have access to your updated `ThemeData` in its context so it will apply the default styling. And in this case you don't have any other choice than wrapping your `Scaffold` with your `Theme` widget.

Comment: The `builderContext` has new `Theme` information in it, hence it should have worked but it didn't.

Comment: Yes `builderContext` has the new `Theme` information, BUT this context is only used to find the `Scaffold` ancestor in the widget tree, when rendering your `SnackBar` it uses the context from your `Scaffold` which does not have the new `ThemeData`.

Comment: This was the line I was looking for, I realized you also wrote similar thing in the post which I overlooked since it was a long answer to read.

Answer (score 1):

`Theme` widget should be parent of `Scaffold` to override this page's theme. Tested it, and it works.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give the reason why wrapping `Scaffold` in `Theme` worked but not `FAB` in `Theme`?